# How can I beat this Dev time in Offspring Fling?

Tags: offspring-fling

How does one pull off the maneuvers required to beat the Dev time for level "049. Keep It Moving"?

The most horrifying part of this level is that -- after heroic effort -- you beat the Gold time, only to discover you have to finish almost **TWICE** as fast to beat the Dev time! What in the world...

This game started off as such a pleasant, puzzle platformer. Now that I'm hooked, I discover that I'm in for more than I bargained for: this is an intense speed run challenge.

So let's talk about level "049. Keep It Moving". By watching the Dev ghost, I have learned a few things, but not nearly enough. There seem to be a few impossible parts (using the word [impossible](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1042123-dirk-gently-s-holistic-detective-agency) here in the sense that there is something we don't know about: with additional information, these ought to become possible, maybe even trivial):

- Right at the beginning of the level, the Dev ghost drops down near the first offspring and immediately jumps to a far away high ledge. This is impossible for me to do normally, let alone while throwing or carrying (!) an offspring.
- In the middle of the level, near the little block island, the Dev ghost seems to be carrying the two offspring up onto the lower ledges. This is impossible because the Seeker Bee is always over there bothering you.
- At the end of the level, the Dev ghost is seen literally flying up onto the high ledge by the exit door. This is impossible because you can't jump that high with even one, let along TWO offspring.

Try my best, I can't get my character to do any of these things. I have tried almost every conceivable button combination in these situations.

Are these secrets revealed at some point later in the game? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I kept digging, and found some more [choice reviews](http://thegemsbok.com/art-reviews-and-articles/video-game-reviews-mid-week-mission-offspring-fling-kyle-pulver/), some of which were only made available recently ([this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAXVdFuPcjw) was only posted within the last few months). Findings are catalogued below.

True to its nature as a precision platformer, this game is hard. (And fun.) Beating the Gold times is a challenge. Beating the Dev times requires detailed knowledge of certain game mechanics:

- Jumping repeatedly in small corridors increases your speed (jumping in an open area has no such effect)
- Picking up offspring in the middle of a jump does not decrease the height of the jump (you will jump as high as if you were not carrying the offspring)
- Thrown offspring can be picked back up in the moments after hitting a wall (they will otherwise fall faster than the player character)
- Bumping the edge of a platform while jumping up onto it -- or over it -- will slow you down a lot (it is much faster to land squarely on top of the platform)
- Bumping the edge of a button while jumping up over it will trigger the button (in this way, toggle buttons can be pushed twice in one jump -- once going up, and another coming down)
- Three impeccably timed button presses in rapid succession can allow you to pickup two children immediately after beginning a jump
- You can parry by facing an enemy (or enemy projectile) and tapping the arrow key towards the enemy (requires frame perfect precision, only works with <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow keys)

And, of course, you simply need to become better at gracefully and perfectly navigating the light and fluffy player character off of, on to, and in between ledges.

AY-YIYI-YI-YI!